# Circuitikz: resistor badly drawn if xscale=-1

Tags: circuitikz

With this simple circuit

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[xscale=-1]
% this xscale must be specified also in the opamp

\draw
(0,0) to [R,l^=$R_1$,-*] (3,0)
;

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

the resistor is drawn with an horizontal line over it. If I remove the `xscale=-1` option, it is correctly drawn instead.

Is this a bug? Can be fixed in any way?

Comment: Not necessarily nice, but not a bug: just the way `circuitikz` works. What is the use case for specifying `xscale=-1` globally? Normally it's just used for those components that need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily nice, but not a bug: just the way `circuitikz` works. Normally `xscale=-1` is not used globally but only used for those components that need it (for example to orient op amps and transistors).

If you really need to set `xscale=-1` globally, you can revert it for individual components by applying the same scaling again. Note that if you place this key after the component key, you must provide the full key path `/tikz/xscale` here to escape `circuitikz`'s key namespace:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[xscale=-1]
% this xscale must be specified also in the opamp

\draw
(0,1) to [xscale=-1,R,l=$R_1$,-*] (3,1)
% or
(0,0) to [R,/tikz/xscale=-1,l^=$R_1$,-*] (3,0)
;

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Aha! Now, it becomes clear what you are actually doing. :-)

Another way to show a "mirrored" version of a circuit is to use `x=-1cm` (or the opposite of whatever your global `x` setting is—the default is `x=1cm`). This allows you to use the same code to show a mirrored circuit, without adding extra `xscale` keys everywhere.

However, this will affect label positions, because you're changing the direction the component is drawn, and the label positions are relative to this direction. You'll need to swap `^` for `_` and vice versa anytime a component is drawn along the mirrored axis (here, the x-axis). Labels for components along the non-mirrored axis (here, the y-axis) are not affected and do not need to be changed.

So, depending on your circuit and how picky you are about label positions, this method may or may not result in fewer changes to the code than the first method:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\begin{scope}
  \draw (0,0)
  to[V=1<\volt>] ++(0,2)
  to[R=$R_1$,-*] ++(2,0)
;\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(5,0)},x=-1cm] % add x=-1cm here and shift to move the mirrored version
  \draw (0,0)
  to[V=1<\volt>] ++(0,2)
  to[R,l_=$R_1$,-*] ++(2,0) % swap label position here; otherwise identical code within the scopes
;\end{scope}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Your example is perfectly related to my answer and is correct. I would like anyway to point out that it won't work if you have a circuit alongside of $R_1$. In that case, in addition to what you explained, it is necessary to change the sign of the x extreme values of the component. So, if you have `(3,0) to [R,/tikz/xscale=-1,l^=$R_2$,-*] (6,0)` the draw will be correct only if you put `(-3,0) to [R,/tikz/xscale=-1,l^=$R_2$,-*] (-6,0)`.

Comment: Of course; because what `xscale=1` is doing is reversing the entire coordinate system: if you have other components, you have to make the relative positions correct. I'll ask again: what is the intent of specifying `xscale=-1` globally? It shouldn't be needed. If I know what you're trying to do, I might be able to address the problem rather than the symptoms.

Comment: It was due to the necessity to draw both a circuit and his symmetrical with just (or almost) the same code. Your answer was very useful and the correction of the coordinates, at least in a simple circuit, is not a hard work.